# I get this error when trying to use CardView and RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I have the beginnings of a very basic app at the moment. It just has one main activity, which has a navigation drawer and one card. When I try and debug the app I get the following error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$ViewHolder.shouldIgnore()' on a null object reference. Below is the code:

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private ScoreCardAdapter adapter;
    private List<ScoreCard> scoreCardList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Setting up the custom toolbar
        Toolbar customToolbar = findViewById(R.id.custom_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(customToolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(null);
        customToolbar.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

        //Creating the menu icon in the appbar
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        if (actionBar != null)
        {
            actionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_menu_black_24dp);
            actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        }

        mDrawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

        // Initializing Drawer Layout and ActionBarToggle
        ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,mDrawerLayout,customToolbar,R.string.openDrawer, R.string.closeDrawer)
        {
            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView)
            {
                // Code here will be triggered once the drawer closes as we don't want anything to happen so we leave this blank
                super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                // Code here will be triggered once the drawer open as we don't want anything to happen so we leave this blank
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            }
        };

        //Setting the actionbarToggle to drawer layout
        mDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);

        //calling sync state is necessay or else your hamburger icon wont show up
        actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();

        scoreCardList = new ArrayList<>();
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        adapter = new ScoreCardAdapter(this, scoreCardList);

        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);


        scoreCardList.add(new ScoreCard("Sunday, 28th January 2018", R.drawable.launcher_logo, "3 -- 2", R.drawable.annan_athletic_fc_logo, "14:00, Forthbank Stadium"));


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed()
    {
        if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START))
        {
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        }
        else
        {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

Adapter:

```
public class ScoreCardAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ScoreCardAdapter.ScoreCardViewHolder>
{
    private Context mCtx;
    private List<ScoreCard> scoreCardList;

    public class ScoreCardViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        public TextView dateTextView;
        public ImageView homeTeamLogoImageView;
        public TextView scoreTextView;
        public ImageView enemyTeamLogoImageView;
        public TextView timeAndLocationTextView;

        public ScoreCardViewHolder(View view)
        {
            super(view);

            dateTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.date_textview);
            homeTeamLogoImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.home_team_logo_imageview);
            scoreTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.score_textview);
            enemyTeamLogoImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.enemy_team_logo_imageview);
            timeAndLocationTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.time_and_location_textview);
        }
    }

    public ScoreCardAdapter(Context mCtx, List<ScoreCard> scoreCardList)
    {
        this.mCtx = mCtx;
        this.scoreCardList = scoreCardList;
    }

    @Override
    public ScoreCardViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
    {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.main_card_layout, parent, false);
        return new ScoreCardViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ScoreCardViewHolder holder, int position)
    {
        ScoreCard scoreCard = scoreCardList.get(position);

        holder.dateTextView.setText(scoreCard.getDate());
        holder.scoreTextView.setText(scoreCard.getScore());
        holder.timeAndLocationTextView.setText(scoreCard.getTimeAndLocation());

        holder.homeTeamLogoImageView.setImageDrawable(mCtx.getResources().getDrawable(scoreCard.getHomeTeamLogo(), null));
        holder.enemyTeamLogoImageView.setImageDrawable(mCtx.getResources().getDrawable(scoreCard.getEnemyTeamLogo(), null));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount()
    {
        return scoreCardList.size();
    }


}
```

Main XML:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.application.andrewhaines.stirlingalbionfc.MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        app:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/custom_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/SAFCRed"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:menu="@menu/nav_menu_list"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_drawer_layout"
        android:theme="@style/NavigationDrawerStyle">
    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

CardXML:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/score_card_overall_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:elevation="3dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/date_textview"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textSize="16sp"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/home_team_logo_imageview"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:contentDescription="home team logo"
                    android:scaleType="fitCenter"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/score_textview"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:textSize="20sp"/>

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/enemy_team_logo_imageview"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:contentDescription="enemy team logo"
                    android:scaleType="fitCenter"/>

            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/time_and_location_textview"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textSize="14sp"/>



        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Logcat:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.application.andrewhaines.stirlingalbionfc, PID: 16411
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.application.andrewhaines.stirlingalbionfc/com.application.andrewhaines.stirlingalbionfc.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$ViewHolder.shouldIgnore()' on a null object reference
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
                   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$ViewHolder.shouldIgnore()' on a null object reference
                      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager.removeAndRecycleAllViews(RecyclerView.java:9728)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.setLayoutManager(RecyclerView.java:1220)
                      at com.application.andrewhaines.stirlingalbionfc.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:79)
                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

I have looked at other NullPointerExcpetion threads, but they did not help!

Comment: Please post the entire logcat output for the exception.

Comment: I added the logcat now

Comment: I have looked at other NullPointerExcpetion threads, but they did not help!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is problem with layout manager you are passing.

```
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

instead, you can try using this for layout manager.

```
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I don't really know why this worked, but all I did was swapped this code:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.application.andrewhaines.stirlingalbionfc.MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        app:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/custom_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/SAFCRed"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:menu="@menu/nav_menu_list"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_drawer_layout"
        android:theme="@style/NavigationDrawerStyle">
    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

With this code:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.application.andrewhaines.stirlingalbionfc.MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/custom_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/SAFCRed"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        app:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:menu="@menu/nav_menu_list"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_drawer_layout"
        android:theme="@style/NavigationDrawerStyle">
    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

So if someone can let me know why making the Toolbar the first child of the DrawerLayout and then the RecyclerView the second one works but having the RecyclerView as the fist child and then the Toolbar as the second doesn't?

Comment: In the first case toolbar is with in recyclerview, the closing is incorrect i think,  if you could correct that and give a shot?

Comment: Yeah that was it! I posted the altered code above which shows the change I made. Its all working now :)

Comment: Great. It's weird,  Android Studio doesn't capture such errors. I mean while in xml,there should be some flag to highlight such errors.